# How to highlight spaces in a tag? (CSS only)

Tags: css

I have the tag

```
<span class="block" style="width:12px;height:17px">&nbsp;tttt&nbsp;ttt&nbsp;ttttt</span>
```

I want to highlight only `&nbsp;`. How can I do it **using only CSS**?

Comment: What do you mean with " highlight only '& nbsp;' " ? How can you highlight "blank spaces" ?!!?

Comment: So technically we have to be able to select the spaces in CSS by some rule and style it? well I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Otherwise you can do it by adding a span instead of &nbsp; with same background-color and color. Something like in the link here. http://jsfiddle.net/JDR48/

Comment: highlight - it's mean I want to find and to paint all spaces in a string. Like using ::first-letter selector only for all entries. I can't add new tags (this strict condition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is no such way to select the space, but if for some reason you really want to do it then, you can try something like this:

```
<span class="block" style="width:12px;height:17px"><span style="background-color:#F00;">&nbsp;</span>tttt<span style="background-color:#F00;">&nbsp;</span>ttt&nbsp;ttttt</span>
```

Put the `&nbsp;` within a span like

```
<span style="background-color:#F00;">&nbsp;</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with only CSS; you will need to wrap each non-breaking space in a `span` and give that `span` a background color. [Wikipedia does this in their article for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space):

```html
In Unicode, it is encoded as <span class="nowrap">U+00A0</span> <span class="unicode" style="background:lightblue">&#160;</span> <span class="smallcaps" style="font-variant:small-caps;">no-break space</span>
```